# How can I get specific diagnostic information on an IP address from Zuul?

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have Zuul and Eureka running, with a bunch of smaller services. Using Eureka, I can see all of the services and their associated host/IP address. Usually, I can boot up multiple instances of another service and Eureka will pick them up for Zuul to route to. I'm currently having an issue where I have three instances of a service registered in Eureka, but Zuul only routes to one of them. I don't know where to go to get diagnostic information from Zuul to understand why it isn't routing to the other two instances. I've tried simple things, like manually sending requests from the Zuul box to the service boxes to make sure they can communicate.

Does Zuul expose an endpoint to list hosts/IP addresses and their status? What are my diagnostic options?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to list all your endpoints with [the routes endpoint](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_the_routes_endpoint)

So, if you running zuul on your localhost on port 8080 you can do a `GET` call to `http://localhost:8080/routes` and you will get something like

```
{
   /stores/**: "http://localhost:8081"
}
```

Depending on the version you are using, you also need to set

```
management.security.enabled = false
```

in the `application.properties`

EDIT:

You can also use the logging mechanism.
Set the loglevel just of the LoadBalancerContext to debug in `application.properties`

```
 #logging
 logging.level.com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext=DEBUG
```

It will log each call that is routed.

Comment: When I call `/routes`, I just get entries like `"/stores/**": "stores-service"`. I assume that's because I configured Zuul with a `serviceId` property instead of a `url` property. Since Zuul keeps track of other info, like number of failures per route, I assumed that there were other web calls like `/routes`, but I haven't really found anything.